# How to declare array inside object?

Tags: angular

I want to declare array inside object, something like this:

```
 customer:any = {customerGeneralInfo:{accounts:[],showBlock:true,showCa:false};
```

How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: in ts im getting an error

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: I think you are missing a }

Comment: If you get an error, you're doing something wrong. It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong without knowing what the error message is.

Comment: yesss @H.Hakvoort thats it... tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are missing on `}`

Try this

```
customer:any = {customerGeneralInfo:{accounts:[],showBlock:true,showCa:false}};
```